# Should I split my dataset if I'm solely trying to understand feature importance?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, feature-engineering, importance

I'm being provided a dataset with several variables in it, and a success metric (1 or 0) at the end. I'm being asked to analyze the dataset and give insights on how to improve the success metric rate.To do this I intend to do a thorough data analysis to study correlations and relationships. However I'm also intending to run a logistic regression to confirm these correlations with the features coefficients.

My question is, **if my sole interest is understanding the most important feature determining a metric, and not building a robust model, should I still split my datasets into 2** ? What benefits do I have splitting it ? Won't my exploratory analysis loose interest if I'm putting away - let's say- 20% ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: No for this you don't necessarily need to split the data, but feature importance is not what you should look at. Understanding the effects at play and being able to advise on how to act to facilitate a desired outcome (intervention) requires a causal understanding of the data.

Comment: one thing you learn by splitting your dataset is the stability of your variable selection algo. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2932.pdf for more.